# Finding edges between each pair of nodes in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, combinatorics

Here I am trying to make a boolean that if no edge exists between a pair of nodes of size 3, print this pair

So, I want to use G.adj and I know how to use it so far with pairs of size 2 but here I am not getting the right results.

examples:

(2, 5, 9) -> print

(0, 7, 8) - > dont print

```
%pylab inline
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import networkx as nx

n = 10
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(range(n))
G.add_edge(0, n-1)
G.add_edge(0, 5)
G.add_edge(1, 6)
G.add_edge(2, 7)
G.add_edge(3, 8)
G.add_edge(4, 9)         
for i in range(n-1):
    G.add_edge(i, i+1)

s = set(itertools.combinations(G.nodes, 3))
for i in s:
    if i not in G.adj:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `G.adj`:

```
AdjacencyView({0: {9: {}, 5: {}, 1: {}}, 1: {6: {}, 0: {}, 2: {}}, 2: {7: {}, 1: {}, 3: {}}, 3: {8: {}, 2: {}, 4: {}}, 4: {9: {}, 3: {}, 5: {}}, 5: {0: {}, 4: {}, 6: {}}, 6: {1: {}, 5: {}, 7: {}}, 7: {2: {}, 6: {}, 8: {}}, 8: {3: {}, 7: {}, 9: {}}, 9: {0: {}, 4: {}, 8: {}}})
```

This is basically a nested dictionary. Evaluating something like `(6,5,0)` in `G.adj` will therefore return `False`, causing your triple to get printed. You can write more elaborate logic to query `G.adj`, such as:

```
adj = G.adj
for x,y,z in s:
    if (adj[x].get(y), adj[x].get(z), adj[y].get(z)) == (None, None, None):
        print((x,y,z))
```

Alternatively, you can go via the adjacency matrix:

```
am = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()
s = set(itertools.combinations(G.nodes, 3))
for x,y,z in s:
    if (am[x,y], am[x,z], am[y,z]) == (0,0,0):
        print((x,y,z))
```